# Best practice to fetch sync

Tags: dvajs

Im trying to get the model `User` which have a relation with `Projects`.
Here is my `models/user.js`

```
 *fetchUser({ payload, callback }, { call, put }) {
      const user = yield call(queryUser, payload);
      yield put({
        type: 'setCurrentUser',
        payload: user,
      });
      if (callback) callback();
    },
```

What is the best practice? Where should I call the function `queryProjects`?
Maybe below this line?

```
const user = yield call(queryUser, payload);
const projects = yield call(queryProjects, user); // new api call
```

Answer (score 0):

### First Approach

Make two models, `users` & `projects`

Then you can do this

```
*fetchUser({ payload, callback }, { call, put }) {
      const user = yield call(queryUser, payload);
      yield put({
        type: 'setCurrentUser',
        payload: user,
      });
      yield put({type: 'projects/fetchByUserId', payload: user.id});
    },

Inside your `projects` model.

*fetchByUserId({payload){
    // do ajax call
}
```

Once you have data for projects you can filter the project array with user id (considering your project has something like `project.user_id`) and show them into the app.

### Second Approach

You can have your backend server send the project list for user in the user object.

```
{
    id: 1,
    username: "foo",
    projects: [
        {id: 1},
        {id: 2}
        {id: 3}
    ]
}
```

I hope it makes sense.